# Rails 4 accepts nested attributes id can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update two models with one form. Everything seems to checkout, expect except both models will not save (not valid) because the required customer_order_id. How do I save the customer_order first, so that it will generate an id and then populate the payment?

```
def create

@customer_order = CustomerOrder.new(customer_order_params)

if current_user.id.present?
@customer_order.user_id = current_user.id
@customer_order.payments.first.user_id = current_user.id      
end 



respond_to do |format|
  if @customer_order.save


    format.html { redirect_to @customer_order, notice: 'Customer order was successfully created.' }
```

When I check if the model(s) are valid? here is the error.message

```
{:"payments.customer_order_id"=>["can't be blank"], :payments=>["is invalid"]}
```

It was my understanding that the customer_order would create the order first, then create the Payment. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is “error.message”?

Comment: {:"payments.customer_order_id"=>["can't be blank"], :payments=>["is invalid"]}

Comment: What does that mean? Where is that from? The error.message thing? Why it returns a hash?

Comment: if is by using debugger.... here is the message generated from the view: Payments customer order can't be blank... it is a validation error. The Payment will not save unless there is a customer_order_id. So the customer order must save first and generate an id. That id should then be inserted into the Payment model.

Comment: Okay, so, then you need to make sure there is a customer for the payment.

Comment: Can you tell me how, I am trying to generate both a CustomerOrder and a Payment at the same time. In the same form.

Comment: There is `build()` method, you can find it from the documentation. There is also [easy-to-understand guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations run *before* saving to the database. It will be impossible to validate the presence of `customer_order_id` in this case since the customer order is not yet saved.

Consider validating the presence of `customer_order` instead. This allows the validation to pass when a customer order is present whether it is saved or not.

#### Caveat

When building records through associations and nested attributes ActiveRecord will make assignments based on inverse associations. In your case the inverse associations being used are `payments` (on `CustomerOrder`) and `customer_order` (on `Payment`). ActiveRecord will use those to set `payment.customer_order` correctly when a payment is built through nested attributes. If ActiveRecord in unable to determine the inverse associations (due to naming, joins in the associations, etc.) then you may need to explicily add the `:inverse_of` option to each association.

Comment: You nailed it, it was the validation of customer_order_id..... I just did a quick search on creating a validation on the models. Are you referring to use: validates_associated? Thanks again! I am a newbie, although starting to get the big picture.

Comment: No, `validates_associated` is a bit different, and honestly I have not ever found myself needing that.  

You should still use presence validation. Change `validates :customer_order_id, presence: true` (your actual code may differ slightly) to `validates :customer_order, presence: true`

Answer (score 0):

In your after create hook create the first payment ( in the customer_order model)

```
#Customer order model
after_create :create_first_payment

def create_first_payment
  self.payments.create(user_id: user_id)
end
```